# Book about a girl stuck in some sort of labyrinth who meets a boy and becomes a double agent for two factions/tribes

Tags: story-identification, books

All I can remember is that it was about a girl who was stuck in some kind of labyrinth. She met a boy at some point, and there were tribes or factions and she was like a double agent for one of them and the one the boy was in. It had creatures, such as massive worm-like creatures and large, ugly, and scary-looking monsters that were fought off or avoided. She wanted to escape (I can't remember if she actually did, but I think so).

I don't know what time period it took place in; they used weapons such as bows and spears, so probably not in modern or future times.

I read the book prior to COVID, though I'm not sure what year—probably between 2018 and 2020. The cover had a lion's head on it, I believe.

I have searched all over every place I possibly could, but I still cannot find it. I read it on Kindle through Amazon Kids+, but it is no longer available. I have found some other books that were removed from there on this site, so I decided to ask about this one.

Comment: Did the book contain any science fiction or fantasy elements? And in roughly which year did you read it?

Comment: it had some fantasy creatures. I read it prior covid im not sure what year though, probably between 2018-2020

Comment: Was the girl from the modern world? Medieval times? Something else?

Comment: Maybe The Maze Runner?

Comment: Margaret Weiss and Tracy Hickman wrote a series of books called The Dark Labyrinth.

Comment: from what I can remember she had lived in the labyrinth her whole life and no one knew anything else. I dont know what time period it was placed they used weapons such as bows and spears, so probably not in modern or future times?

Comment: @Mr. Watigo - Do you have any recollection of what the cover looked like?

Comment: it had a lion head on it i believe

Comment: @Mr. Watigo - So probably not _[Children of Icarus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29065483-children-of-icarus)_ then. That has a pair of wings on the cover.

Comment: @Mr. Watigo - Actually, the sequel, _[Children of Daedala](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36049722-children-of-daedala)_ does have a lion's head on it. Could that be the book you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Children of Daedala](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36049722-children-of-daedala)*** (2018) by Caighlan Smith.

It's the second and currently latest book in the *[Children of Icarus](https://www.goodreads.com/series/216985-children-of-icarus)* series, and the cover has a lion's head on it.

[image: Front cover of "Children of Daedala" (2018) by Caighlan Smith.]

In the first book, *[Children of Icarus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29065483-children-of-icarus)* (2016), the main character (her real name isn't revealed) is initially a shy, 16-year-old girl born and raised in a city where some children are chosen to enter a labyrinth, through which they can supposedly reach a place called Alyssia and become angels. She enters the labyrinth with her more confident best friend, Clara, but the labyrinth turns out to be full of monsters and Clara is soon killed. The main character subsequently assumes Clara's identity and becomes involved with a group of children called the Fates, one of whom is Clara's older brother. Then, after being cast out by the Fates, she's taken under the wing of a female warrior known as the Executioner, who teaches her survival skills.

From a [review](https://manhattanbookreview.com/product/children-of-icarus/) of the first book:

> In Daedalum, children between the ages of ten and sixteen can be chosen to be Icarii, the Blessed of Icarus, who are sent into the Labyrinth surrounding their city. If they make it through the Labyrinth, they reach Alyssia and become angels like the slumbering Icarus. To be Chosen is a great honor.
>
> To be Chosen is to meet death. The Labyrinth is nothing like they’ve been told. It is a place of unspeakable horrors. There is no magick to keep the Icarii from hunger, thirst, or weariness. There are only nightmare beasts.
>
> Clara has wanted to be Chosen her whole life. This is the last year she is eligible. When she and her best friend are Chosen, things seem to be perfect. They aren’t. Don’t be fooled. Almost straight from the gate, Clara is killed, along with many other Icarii, when a flock of harpies attack. Her friend assumes her name, quite through an accidental misunderstanding. She and a few other fledgling Icarii are rescued by a group from a place called Fates. They are taken in, taught how to survive in this harsh world they now inhabit.
>
> But “Clara’s” misrepresentation gets her into more trouble than she bargained for. Cast out from Fates, she is then taken in by a mysterious figure known as the Executioner, who teaches her even more valuable survival skills. The Executioner’s greatest gifts, however, come from an journal and the secrets it holds.

In the second book, the main character has now been in the labyrinth for six months and is much more formidable than she was when she first entered it, capable of killing monsters on her own with the skills she was taught by the Executioner and the various weapons she's acquired, which include a bow and arrows.

From a Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2329287543) of the second book:

> Our story picks up basically right where it left off. The main heroine is still unnamed. Throughout the book, she is called still Clara and the new nickname of Fey Bell. She is living alone in the labyrinth now that the Executioner is dead. She has basically become a bad-ass. With what the Executioner taught her she is able to down screechers by herself and kill diggers. She likes being alone. She carries a ton of weapons: a chain, ax, arrows and a bow, and a spiked ball and chain to name a few. She also weaves spikes into her braids so anyone who attacks and grabs her hair with slice their hands.

According to this [review](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/688996) of the second book, the main character infiltrates two warring factions, Kleos and Harmonia, to find out which if either of them was responsible for an attack on the Fates, some of whom she is still loyal to.

> In this sequel to 2016's *Children of Icarus*, a nameless protagonist must navigate warring factions of teens thrust into a labyrinth to fend for themselves, all while struggling with the memories of being exiled from one of these factions when she was a little girl. The protagonist recounts her complicated history in Fates, the faction to which she belonged, as well as her experiences after being sent away to die, which left her distrustful yet self-sufficient. When Kleos and Harmonia—the warring all-male and all-female factions, respectively—are implicated in an attack on a Fates base, she infiltrates both groups to uncover the truth and save those in Fates to whom she is still loyal.